# Implementing a spherical camera view also with the possibility to take pictures via app

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, 360-degrees

I would like to implement a spherical camera in the application also with the possibility to take a picture.

I want to use camera-api2.

My questions are as follows:

1. It is possible?
2. Are existing any libraries?
3. Is it better to open the
   camera via the Intent?